# ArgumentNullException when initializing site

Tags: openrasta

I am in the process of evaluating several service frameworks and one of them is OpenRasta.

Despite being taken a bit aback for the lack of organization (multiple source code repositories, lack of binary downloads, outdated build instructions and the end result of the build, *OpenRasta.dll*, has version 0.0.0.0 after building the openrasta-core repository), I managed my way to start building a site with a service that serves a bit of Xml (I did include OpenRasta.Hosting.AspNet and configured the handlers and modules as per IIS or Cassini).

But the very first time I hit the site (both IIS Express and VS Dev Server) I get a `ArgumentNullException` coming from the `PipelineStage.cs`. Apparently the `pipeline.CallGraph` property is null.

My configuration source is a mere:

```
ResourceSpace.Has
   .ResourcesOfType<CatalogCollection>()
   .AtUri("/catalogs")
   .HandledBy<CatalogsHandler>()
   .AsXmlDataContract();
```

As I mentioned I am using the code I cloned from the openrasta-core repository as of yesterday.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try wrapping resource registrations in

```
using (OpenRastaConfiguration.Manual)
{
//code
}
```

Also check this out;

https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-stable/wiki/Building-Your-First-OpenRasta-Website

Hope this helps

Comment: That was exactly the problem!So stupid to not follow the basic example point by point and being carried out by the sexy configuration API. It could give a better exception message, though...

Comment: Agreed the message isn't that obvious.  When you think about sort of makes sense "I don't know how to handle this" i.e. it's a problem with the handler registration. It would be good if OpenRasta threw an exception when no registrations where found on app start.